# Passing the access token within the Facebook Places check-in method

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I would like to get an access token so I can check a user into a place using [Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk). How would I go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkins connection is in the documentation

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

> issuing an HTTP POST request to PROFILE_ID/checkins

Grab your $user

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

Pass the `publish_checkins` permission in the scope array when you call the `getLoginUrl` call.

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'publish_checkins'));
```

Set up the data for the checkin

```
$checkin['post'] = array(
'access_token' => $facebook->getAccessToken(),
'place' => 'PLACE_ID',
'message' =>'Blank Message',
'picture' => 'http://www.example.com/picture.jpg',
'coordinates' => json_encode(array(
   'latitude'  => '_latitude',
   'longitude' => '_longitude',
   'tags' => $user),
 )
 );
```

Issue an API call to the PROFILE_ID in question,

```
$facebook->api('/'.$user.'/checkins', 'post', $checkin['post']);
```

Comment: Im getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' for the checkin array whats wrong? @phwd

Comment: Even when i balance the brackets i'm still getting the unexpected ')'syntax error I don't know what went wrong this thing is frustrating if you could set it out and give me a .txt file and see if you get the same error Thanks btw i'm in Canada too @phwd

Answer (score 0):

Lots of good examples here.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/